# soql query to get the Account id and name which have related opportunities whose status is either close won/Close lost

Tags: sql, database, salesforce, rdbms, soql

```
SELECT AccountId, Account.name
FROM Opportunity
WHERE StageName LIKE '%Closed%'
```

I seek a query that works the same but should be called "From Account". Also that returns records that have null as their name or AccountId.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Account
WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT AccountId 
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE StageName IN ('Closed Won', 'Closed Lost')
)
```

It's almost verbatim in the documentation, you could have searched bit more.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm

> (...)the following query returns account IDs if an associated
> opportunity is lost

```
SELECT Id, Name 
FROM Account 
WHERE Id IN 
  ( SELECT AccountId
    FROM Opportunity
    WHERE StageName = 'Closed Lost' 
  )
```